# Python call multiple commands in a funktion by pressing a button

Tags: python, function, button, tkinter

I have a problem with my code:
I want that the OK-button (tkinter) in a popup-window (exp_Name) makes three things when it gets pressed:

- First it should store a string from the Entry (in the popup-window) in a global variable

  ```
  exp_name = entry.get()
  ```
- Second it should open another window

  ```
  app.show_frame(PageOne)
  ```
- Third it should close the popup-window

  ```
  popup.destroy
  ```

I tried to call a function, but I have no idea how I should close the popup window in a separate function. And also how I should store the Entry in a global variable in this separate function.
Thanks a lot!!
Here the whole code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

global exp_name
exp_name = "Hello"

def exp_Name():
    popup = tk.Tk()
    popup.geometry("800x400")
    label=ttk.Label(popup, text="Enter Something:")
    label.pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10)
    entry = ttk.Entry(popup)
    entry.pack()

##Here is the problem...
    OK_btn=ttk.Button(popup, text="OK", command= lambda: [app.show_frame(PageOne),exp_name = entry.get(), popup.destroy])
    OK_btn.pack()

    Close_btn=ttk.Button(popup, text="Close",command = popup.destroy)
    Close_btn.pack()
    popup.mainloop()


class Steppermovementsapp(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        tk.Tk.iconbitmap(self, default="images/Icon_fly.ico")
        tk.Tk.wm_title(self, "Drosophila ADF apparatus")

        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.frames={}
        for F in (StartPage, PageOne):
            frame = F(container, self)
            self.frames[F] = frame
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        self.show_frame(StartPage)

    def show_frame(self, cont):
        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()

class StartPage(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):

        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        exp_btn = ttk.Button(self, text="Start experiment",command=exp_Name)
        exp_btn.pack()

class PageOne(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        label =ttk.Label(self, text=exp_name)
        label.pack()

app = Steppermovementsapp()
app.geometry("{0}x{1}".format(app.winfo_screenwidth(),app.winfo_screenheight()))
app.mainloop()
```

This is how I tried it with a function:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

global exp_name
exp_name = "Hello"

class sidefunctions(tk.Tk):
    def func_three(self):
        app.show_frame(PageOne)
        exp_name = self.entry.get()
        popup.destroy

    def exp_Name(self):
        self.popup = tk.Tk()
        self.popup.geometry("800x400")
        self.label=ttk.Label(self,text="Enter Something:")
        self.label.pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10)
        self.entry = ttk.Entry(self)
        self.entry.pack()

        self.OK_btn=ttk.Button(self,text="OK", command= self.func_three)
        self.OK_btn.pack()

        self.Close_btn=ttk.Button(self,text="Close",command = 
self.popup.destroy)
        self.Close_btn.pack()
        self.popup.mainloop()


class Steppermovementsapp(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        tk.Tk.iconbitmap(self, default="images/Icon_fly.ico")
        tk.Tk.wm_title(self, "Drosophila ADF apparatus")

        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.frames={}
        for F in (StartPage, PageOne):
            frame = F(container, self)
            self.frames[F] = frame
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        self.show_frame(StartPage)

    def show_frame(self, cont):
        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()

class StartPage(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):

        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        exp_btn = ttk.Button(self, text="Start experiment",command=sidefunctions().exp_Name)
        exp_btn.pack()

    class PageOne(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        label =ttk.Label(self, text=exp_name)
        label.pack()

app = Steppermovementsapp()
app.geometry("{0}x{1}".format(app.winfo_screenwidth(),app.winfo_screenheight()))
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: _"I tried to call a function,"_ please show that, because that is exactly how you do it. You create a function that does everything you want, then you associate that function with the button.